# show post by id , but why just only first id can read

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I have script `wordpress` , this code show post by `id`
here my code :

```
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
$f = cherry_get_option('blog-featured-post',false);
foreach ($f as $fs ) {
$q = new WP_Query( array(
'post__in' => array($fs),
'orderby' => 'date',
'order' => 'asc'
 ) );}

 if ( $q->have_posts() ) : while ( $q->have_posts() ) : $q->the_post();
 //show post 
 the_title();
 endwhile; endif;
 endwhile; else:
 echo "no post found";
 endif;
 wp_reset_query();
```

nah from that code `$fs`will output id post what will display , 
i am try to `vardump($fs)` it work fine (the output is `string(4) "1254" string(4) "1310"`) but in `post_in` just first id can read (`string(4) "1254"`) I dont know what happen with my code , if anyone can help , i will happy

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do? It looks like you are creating multiple queries which appears to be inefficient. Also, if you're only getting one value in `post__in` because it's a `foreach` loop.

Comment: yeah actually , i want to show 2 post or more use `foreach` , but why ,only ! post can show

Comment: The problem now is that you are creating a **new** query for every single `foreach`. You need to create the array **before** using it in `post__in`